# UICollectionView Tap Selects More Than One Cell

Tags: selection, uicollectionview, uitapgesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell

I have a strange problem when tapping a single UICell in UICollectionView and then scrolling down or up in the UICollectionView I see that more one cell is selected.  The other cells that are selected that were not tapped seem to be randomly selected throughout the UICollectionView layout.  I have 3 columns of cells and many rows in the UICollectionView.

In my code I have the following:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)myCV didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    LogInfo(@"Item Selected");
    // highlight the cell user tapped on
    UICollectionViewCell  *cell = [myCV cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell.layer setBorderWidth:10.0f];
    cell.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 108/255. green: 166/255. blue: 16/255. alpha:1.0].CGColor;
    cell.layer.CornerRadius = 10;

}
```

The highlight code just puts a border on the tapped cell.

Is there a way to make sure that only the cell that is tapped is selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because cells can be re-used right? thats why you are getting this result.

Solution is

1. Save the selected indexpath at somewhere.
2. Subclass your cell from UICollectionViewCell, then override UICollectionViewCell's **prepareForReuse** method, there you have to reset from all the formatting you have done (in didSelectItemAtIndexPath method) to their default values and make the cell ready to use again. More about **prepareForReuse** is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/Reference/Reference.html)
3. Apply the same formatting again in cellForRowItemAtIndexPath to selected cell which indexpath you have saved first. thats it!

**But finally, I would suggest that don't do any cell formatting kind of things directly here. Try to understand UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes and use it to do these kind of stuff there.**

Comment: Hi Jirune.  Thank you for replying."Save the selected indexpath at somewhere."  Could you explain a bit more where I should be saving it?

Comment: Hmm.Just declare one global NSIndexPath variable, then assign the selected indexpath to that variable, now based on that stored index you just apply your formattings in cellForItemAtIndexPath thats it..