# Values Repeat When Scrolling in TableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, custom-cell, prepareforreuse

When I tap a button in a custom cell and then scroll down (or up) another cell button is also tapped. I see that it's tapped because the button outlet that I created for the button is disabled.

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has a reuseIdentifier for the cell:

```
var cell: FeedTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MusicCell") as? FeedTableViewCell
```

Considering I have the `degueueReusableCellWithId` in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` do I need a `prepareForReuse`? When I add the `prepareForReuse` in my custom cell file, the cell just goes back to the default values (obviously because I reset it to the default values). Problem is I want it to keep the value of each indexPath.row.

This is how I'm querying the values:

```
 override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className:"Music")

        if(objects?.count == 0)
        {
            query.cachePolicy = PFCachePolicy.CacheThenNetwork
        }

        query.orderByAscending("videoId")

        return query
    }
```

This is the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     return  objects!.count
    }


   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        var cell: FeedTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? FeedTableViewCell
        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FeedTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? FeedTableViewCell
        }
        if let pfObject = object {
               //I took out the irrelevant methods. I can add them if that makes a difference... 
                var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
                if votes == nil {
                    votes = 0
        }
        cell?.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)"

}
```

I'm registering this in the `viewDidLoad` above the super.viewDidLoad()

```
 tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "FeedTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

This is my  button query in the customCell:

```
@IBAction func heartButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(parseObject != nil) {
            if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                votes!++

                parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
                parseObject!.saveInBackground()

                votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)"
            }
        }
        heartOutlet.enabled = false
}
```

Any help and suggestions mean a lot.

Thank you.

---

*REFRENCE LINKS I USED:*

I referred to several links but they were in objective-c and didn't help:

[UICollectionView Tap Selects More Than One Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416189/uicollectionview-tap-selects-more-than-one-cell)

[How to use prepareForReuse method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362713/how-to-use-prepareforreuse-method)

I also referred to the docs, and that didn't help much.

Comment: Add the code of UITableView DataSource Methods

Comment: Where i'm querying and sending the data from the tableView? Or from the custom cell? @HarikrishnanT

Comment: Tbale view data source methods include `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, `numberOfCellsInTableView` etc. please post the code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`(and `willDisplayCell` if you are using that too). There has to be something wrong you are doing in there that causes the issue.

Comment: Just updated the question, thank you @HarikrishnanT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you have posted, it is clear that you are not setting the `enabled` property of the `UIButton` with respect to the `DataSource`(The array and its objects you are using to load the tableview, that is the elements in `objects` array). Whatever objects that array contains, add a property to determine if the condition for the button should be true or false, and then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set the enabled property of the button according to that. When the button is clicked, add a callback to the ViewController(using a delegate) and set the property there.

**Sample Code**

In custom cell class:

```
protocol CellButtonDelegate
{
    func buttonClicked(cell : PFTableViewCell)
}

public var delegate : CellButtonDelegate?

public var buttonEnabled : Bool?
{
    get
    {
        return heartOutlet.enabled
    }
    set
    {
        heartOutlet.enabled = newValue
    }
}

@IBAction func heartButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        if(parseObject != nil) {
            if var votes:Int? = parseObject!.objectForKey("votes") as? Int {
                votes!++

                parseObject!.setObject(votes!, forKey: "votes")
                parseObject!.saveInBackground()

                votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)"
            }
        }
        delegate?.buttonClicked(self)
}
```

In ViewController:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {

        var cell: FeedTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as? FeedTableViewCell
        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("FeedTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? FeedTableViewCell
        }
        if let pfObject = object {
               //I took out the irrelevant methods. I can add them if that makes a difference... 
                var votes:Int? = pfObject["votes"] as? Int
                if votes == nil {
                    votes = 0
        }
        cell?.buttonEnabled = objects[indexPath.row].isEnabled //The new property you need to add. true by default
        cell?.delegate = self //Make sure you implement the delgate
        cell?.votesLabel?.text = "\(votes!)"    
        return cell?
}

func buttonClicked(cell : PFTableViewCell)
{
     //Here, get the indexPath using the cell and assign the new property in the array.
}
```

Please note that the above code is rough. Just get the idea from the code and implement it as per your requirement.

Comment: I'm using ParseUI to get the objects, so `objects` array is a ParseUI property that stores those objects. Can you provide some sample code? I'm having trouble understanding the logic of where this should be placed. Isn't it only relevant in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Why would it be relevant in the `objects` array if I'm having a problem with the UIButton and the datasource? @HarikrishnanT

Comment: Sample code added. You will have to make some changes in the current logic after referring the code I posted.

Comment: Trying it now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: 2 problems:  I get this error: `Cannot assign value of type "FeedTableViewController" to type CellButtonDelegate?` for this link: '        cell?.delegate = self` I added the delegate in the cell like this: `var delegate : CellButtonDelegate?` right under the class definition of the cell. and for this function:  `func buttonClicked(cell : PFTableViewCell){  cell.buttonEnabled = objects![indexPath.row].isEnabled = true  }` which I put in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` right under the other methods and i get this error: `value of type PFTableViewCell has no member buttonEnabled`. Suggestions?

Comment: I'm also getting an error when adding the delegate to the class definition*. @HarikrishnanT

Comment: Delegate shouldn't be added in class definition, put it right outside the class definition below the import statements. I thought you were aware of the basic syntax. :-)

Comment: Hey, I did add it there but I got an error so I declared in right below... EDIT: Now i fixed it and added it on the top. I got it initialized and it works now. My issue is making a an array and adding boolean condition for each button. I can't make it a dictionary, which is what I'm trying. @HarikrishnanT

Comment: The proper way of doing it adding a boolean property to the object of the array `objects` to determine if the button has to be enabled or not. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96263/discussion-between-lukesivi-and-harikrishnan-t).

Comment: How do I add a property to the array objects to determine if the button has been enabled or not? Sorry for the newbie questions! :) @Harikrishnan